# Android Xamarin - Variable initiation asks method name

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

```
Button[] c = new Button[255] (this);
```

For some reason, Xamarin Studio asks me for a Method name and points me at the beginning of the word "New"

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I dont have experience in Xamrin, but I think thats not the right way to initialize the array .

Comment: The `(this)` part is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing syntax... You cannot use the enumerator and the method call in one line...

```
Button[] c = new Button[255]; // Initialise an array of buttons, length 255.
c[0] = new Button(this); // Add a new button to index 0 of the array.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var b = new Button[255];

b[0] = new Button(this);
```